# About CI/CD for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cicd

I am using kubernetes.
I can do docker builds from GitHub and upload them to docker hub on our own.
However, I would like to automate the creation and updating of pods.
How about Circle CI for example?

Or is it possible to use the k8s library to update the pods?

Comment: You may be interested in [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Flux](https://fluxcd.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ArgoCD image updator](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

> The Argo CD Image Updater can check for new versions of the container images that are deployed with your Kubernetes workloads and automatically update them to their latest allowed version using Argo CD. It works by setting appropriate application parameters for Argo CD applications, i.e. similar to argocd app set `--helm-set image.tag=v1.0.1` - **but in a fully automated manner**.

[auto-update-features](https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#features)

With auto image update, you just need to update the image in the docker registry and the image updater will take of the rest.

Here is the minimal annotation that will be required for the image updater to consider the specific application

```
      annotations:
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: image-alias=1234.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging-app
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.update-strategy: latest
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.force-update: "true"
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.allow-tags: "regexp:^build-version-tag-[0-9]+$"
        argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-alias.pull-secret: pullsecret:argocd/aws-registry-secret
```

[argocd-demo-app](https://github.com/adiii717/argocd-demo-app)

Comment: Thank you.
For example, is it possible to fire an update event at any given time?
For example Slack → aws lambda → argo cd → kubernetes pod

Comment: yes, Argocd has a cli and you can trigger an update or sync app, for example `argocd app set $APP_NAME --release-name $APP_NAME -p replicaCount=1 -p image.tag="my-new-release"`